# How do you define variables locally then reference them in a remote machine?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Let's say I have 3 functions; A, B and C. Obviously this is super watered down but the logic is there.

A is a function that gathers a name.

```
function A {
Set-Variable -Scope Script -Name "First" -Value (Read-Host "First name?")
Set-Variable -Scope Script -Name "Last" -Value (Read-Host "Last name?")
}
```

Function B will use this name to create a O365 user with an msol session. No big deal.

```
function B {
Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds 
"Add user foo"
$Name = "$Script:First $Script:Last"
"Success!"
}
```

While function C uses the name from A but references it within a PSSession to a remote AD server. This is where my knowledge totally breaks down. I've tried everything I know to reference these local variables within C.

```
function C {
New-ADUser
$Name = "$Script:First $Script:Last"
} 


New-PSSession -computername AD -credential $ADcreds

Invoke-Command -ComputerName AD -ScriptBlock ${function:C} -credential $ADcreds

Remove-PSSession $s0
```

But they are totally wiped. I've tried to invoke a script block first to kind of define them again using the old data with no luck. My `$Script:Name` always comes up null in the PSSession.

Am I missing something huge?

Comment: Hi, [this could help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using:` variable prefix should work here. If not, you should define a `Param` section within your function and pass the arguments using the `-Argument` parameter to the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet.

```
$scriptBlockC = {
    New-ADUser
    $Name = "$using:First $using:Last"
}  

Invoke-Command -ComputerName AD -ScriptBlock $scriptBlockC -credential $ADcreds
```

Note that I removed the function keyword since you are just defining a scriptblock.